# Is it possible to use something like stunt wire harness to reduce the stress on the back and spine?

Tags: ergonomics

I have lower back pain and my lumbar muscle frequently fatigue due to long time sitting. I just got this odd idea of using some kind of harness system to hoist myself up during working to reduce the stress on the lumbar muscle and spine. Theoretically will this work?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should seek advice from a physical therapist or a medical specialist regarding these issues. Back pain can have serious consequences, treat them seriously.

Comment: @Jeroen I did and I am doing physical therapy regularly. Here I just want to have some technical discussion.

Comment: This is not the place to hold such a discussion, unfortunately. This is not a workplace specific issue. Discuss with an expert.

Comment: I don't think stunt wire harnesses are intended to be worn & used for extended periods of time. I very much doubt they'd be comfortable enough to use uninterrupted for hours on end.

Answer (score 8):

**Do not do this.** You can seriously hurt yourself.

Not just medically by pulling yourself apart incorrectly, but doing this is major DIY that requires proper securing to major support structure. Even simple screws into studs isn't going to be strong enough if it supports your body weight.

You intend to only lift a portion of your weight, but if you slip, you're pulling the entire thing down with 100% of your weight and it might include a wall or the roof, hence the major DIY to have a secure structure.

I've been in physio therapy machines in treatment centres, and those things are basically giant exercise machines. Even a simple arm exercise for the elderly have huge support beams. I think they're designed to hold up the person in case they slip.